# Swift - arc4random() could not find an overload for '%' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift, overloading, sender, arc4random

I have a UISlider to give a range of a radius of search (for 5 - x miles, max x=100 miles), and I want to be able to get a random radius distance within this range.

```
@IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider){
   //gives a range (minimum range 5 miles, maximum range 5 - 100 miles)
   var range = (sender.value*95)+5
   //gives a random distance in miles from within that range
   var distance = Int((arc4random()%(range))+1)
}
```

When I try to assign "distance" I get the error "could not find an overload for '%' that accepts the supplied arguments".

Comment: Of course you _could_ try to do _some_ research before wasting Stack Overflow bandwidth on this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `sender.value` is a UISlider.value that is a `Float`. `arc4random` is a `UInt32` which is your main issue here.

What you've done is try to convert the whole thing to an `Int` when you just need the internal components to be matching first. So get the `range` and the `arc4random` to the same type (I've done a `Float` here) and then do the casting you want =

```
Int(Float(arc4random()) % range + 1)
```

You of course could also use `arc4random_uniform` as the other commenters have stated as in :

```
arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range)) + 1
```

which is actually much better if you don't really care about the value of your `range` (especially any decimal part).

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20282

Answer (score 1):

Use `arc4random_uniform()`

```
let distance = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range)) - 1
```

`arc4random_uniform()` will perform the modulo operation without bias.